# Faster data upload without BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, csv, amazon-ec2

I am using the following snippet to upload data from a **CSV** into a table in located in an *SQL Server* Instance on *Amazon EC2*. From what I have read, it seems that Amazon EC2 does not support **BULK INSERT** operations or **OPENROWSET**, so the upload speed is lacking obviously.

My question, is there a faster way to upload than this?

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            columns = next(reader)
            query = 'insert into myTable({0}) values ({1})'
            query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            for data in reader:
                cursor.execute(query, data)
            cursor.commit()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.  You're adding each row separately.  Provide multiple rows in one insert to increase speed substantially.  I'm sure there's a limit on how big the insert could be... Around 100 or 1000 rows at once should be a decent starting point of they aren't unusually large rows.

To do it you'll want to accumulate the values list in an array, then once the array is at the size limit flush out the data with an insert.

Make sure to do the flush again after all errors are read, as the csv probably doesn't have a number of rows equally divisible by the size you choose.

Comment: Interesting idea, I was scared of overloading the execute command just in case. but I will have a fiddle and see what I can do.

Comment: Interestingly, it took about 40 minutes to upload 143000 rows with 32 columns in each row! :D

Comment: I would expect to be able to add that kind of volume in less than or in the range of hundreds of seconds.

Comment: Ok so after some time, I have eliminated the CSV from the chain altogether, it has increased the performance, but Im still inserting 1 row at a time. I am going to rewrite the insert query today and see If I can do what you suggest. Thanks for the idea! :)